# Word count in Quarto

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I would love a convenient and easy way to print my word count automatically in quarto and stumbled across this nice add-in from Ben Marwick:

https://github.com/benmarwick/wordcountaddin

It is sound for rmarkdown and I presumed it should be no issue with quarto too. However, when I use the add-in, though it can count out the number of words within my RStudio session, it doesn't print it in my final pdf format and just returns [1] NA.

```
{r, #wordcountdev, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, echo = FALSE}

wordstats <- wordcountaddin:::text_stats('CMI Write Up.qmd')  
words <- substr(wordstats[3], start=19, stop=30)
print(words)
```

I don't understand what is going on here, it is seemingly simple, would anyone know of a better way to achieve what I'm trying?

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at the [wordcounts](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/wordcount) pandoc filter, e.g. as a starting point it prints the number of words in the body to the console while rendering:

```
---
format: html
filters: [wordcounts.lua]
---

Hello there, how many words are in the body?
```

[image]

*Or*: You can use the development version (`devtools::install_github("benmarwick/wordcountaddin",  type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)`) of the above mentioned package:

````
---
format: html
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| label: wordstats
#| warning: false
#| message: false
wordcount <- wordcountaddin::text_stats('wordcount.qmd')
words <- substr(wordcount[3], start=19, stop=30)
```

Hello there, how many words are in the body? 
There are `r words` words in the whole document.
````

[image]

**Update**: There exist a new quarto filter for wordcounts: https://github.com/andrewheiss/quarto-wordcount

Comment: Is this possible in RStudio?

Comment: Yes, but using the dev version, you can also use the addin - see my edit.